# How to check If cin buffer contains the same value for 0.5sec (C++)

Tags: c++

I want to make a program so that when I type in `1` it will print `go ahead` infinite times and like that 2-go left 3-go right. And when I enter `0` it should stop everything and print `!!!stop!!!`

I have tried many things but I can't even make the `1` command work. Please help.

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include<iostream>
   using std::cout;
   using std::cin;
   using std::endl;


    int main()
    {
        int value;
        cout << "Would you please enter the command " << endl;
        cout << " _______________________" << endl;
        cout << " 1- go ahead           |" << endl;
        cout << " _______________________" << endl;
        cout << " 2- make a left turn   |" << endl;
        cout << " _______________________" << endl;
        cout << " 3- make a right turn  |" << endl;
        cout << " _______________________" << endl;
        cout << " 4- go back            |" << endl;
        cout << " _______________________" << endl;
        cout << " 0- stop everything    |" << endl;
        cout << " _____________________________________________________" << endl;

        cin >> value;

        switch (value)
        {
        case 1:
            while (int value == 1)
            {
                cout << "  * go ahead " << endl;
                if (value == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << " * turn left " << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << " * turn right " << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << " * reverse " << endl;
            break;
        case 0:
            cout << " !!!Stop!!! " << endl;
            break;

        }


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `'1'` is not the same `1`

Comment: what value you entered, 0 or 48 ? change the `case '1':` to `case 1:` & so on

Comment: Also `for (int value == 1)` is not valid C++ and shouldn't compile

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Answer (score 3):

`for(value==1)` is no valid C++ syntax and even if it would be, your code would print "go ahead" infinitely after 1 has been entered.
Besides that, your `switch` cases are checking for ASCII 1 instead of numeric 1. Change `'1'` to `1`.

You need to surround your input switch statement with some kind of loop like this:

```
int value = 0;
do{
    cin >> value;
    switch(value){
        case 1:
            cout << "go ahead" << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "turn left" << endl;
            break;
        case 3: 
            cout << "turn right" << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "reverse" << endl;
            break;
        case 0:
            cout << "stop" << endl;
            break;            
    }    
}while(value!=0);
```

This Code will ask for input and print the direction afterwards.

Comment: Well the problem is that the "go ahead ", "turn left, right" and "reverse" signs have to be continuously written (I mean like this while(true){cout<<"Go ahead "<<endl;}) until the user inputs another number lets say 2 and so on and when the user enters 0 everything should stop. but the problem here is input how do you input something which would not impact the loop.

Comment: As far as i've read it's not possible in standard c++ as it's terminal/os dependant. This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed

Answer (score 3):

You have three problems.  Firstly, `'1'` is a character literal and `1` is an integer literal (and I know of no implementation where they have the same value).  You need to get rid of the quotes.

Secondly, `for (int value == 1)` is not valid C++.  You need to change this to `while (value == 1)`.

Finally, and most significantly, nothing inside the loop will allow `value` to change.  It will be an infinite loop (and hence undefined behaviour).  You will need to run the indefinite loop on one thread, and do input in a loop on the other thread.

(Also, please don't use [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/771073))

Comment: You could add a short explanation of why not to use `using namespace std;`.

Comment: @O.O.Balance : Linked instead.

Comment: ok but why don't use using namespace std; it is faster in that way

Comment: @DavidDanielyan : Follow [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/771073).  In short, it is only faster to type, and speed of typing is never the limiting factor.

Answer (score 1):

remove `''` in case statements

```
switch (value)
    {
    case 1:
        for (value == 1)
        {
            cout << "  * go ahead " << endl;
            if (value == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << " * turn left " << endl;
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << " * turn right " << endl;
        break;
    case 4:
        cout << " * reverse " << endl;
        break;
    case 0:
        cout << " !!!Stop!!! " << endl;
        break;

    }
```

Comment: The `for (value == 1)` thing is still here.

Comment: `for (value == 1)` ? `for` or `if` ?

Comment: since the OP wants it printed "infinite times", it seems `for` is correct

Comment: I am sorry I didn't finish editing before uploading I was still editing the code. But the main problem here is  that the "go ahead ", "turn left, right" and "reverse" signs have to be continuously written (I mean like this while(true){cout<<"Go ahead "<<endl;}) until the user inputs another number lets say 2 and so on and when the user enters 0 everything should stop. but the problem  is input how do you input something which would not impact the loop. I was thinking If I could check if nothing is entered in the cin buffer for lets say 0.5 seconds then continue the loop.